# Combined two Elements By Class Name that have the same substring?

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote this code for webscraping in VBA:

```
Sub Scrape()   
    Dim Document As HTMLDocument
    Dim Browser As InternetExplorer

    Set Browser = New InternetExplorer

    Do While Browser.Busy And Not Browser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set Document = Browser.Document

    Set Elements1 = Document.getElementsByClassName("Prices-red")
    Set Elements2 = Document.getElementsByClassName("Prices-white")   
End Sub
```

I would like to combine these two elements in one Element named Elements only searching for "Prices".
Is this possible? Like we do in Access `Prices *` for queries.

Comment: Show us some data of how it is in the web and how you intend to get the data. As the getElementByClassName will only get the information of each specific class.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a partial solution, but it might be worthy for you to have a look. If you know that all the elements you look for always have the same tag (e.g. in your case I guess you look for stock prices, which means they usually are all in the same type of tag, let's say `td`):

1) create a custom collection

```
Dim allPrices As New Collection
```

2) get all the `td` elements

```
Set allElements = Browser.Document.getElementsByTagNam("td")
```

3) Loop through the elements and get only the ones which have a class starting by "Price":

```
For Each element In allElements
    If (element.hasAttribute("class")) And (element.getAttribute("class") Like "Price*") Then
        allPrices.Add element
    End If
Next element
```

At the end of this loop, all the elements having a `class = "Price"` something will be into a unique collection called `allPrices`, to hence allow you to use it without running the same code over several similar collections of HTML elements.

You might want to go into this direction to find something more flexible: I had thought about

```
Set allElements = Browser.Document.All
```

but I fear there are nested collections inside, so your elements might not be on the direct index but you might need to loop again and again inside the elements, which is neither proper nor safe. 
Don't hesitate to leave a comment if you need some additional help, it's a method I've myself never tested before, let's say it's rather an idea about how to approach the problem.